# String created from input stream not matching up in if statement

Tags: java, android, inputstream

For some reason my String which is Dublin, will not match up with my String I have obtained from a text file in my assets folder. 
Here is the code where I obtained the string

```
InputStream is;
String text = "";
try {
    is = getAssets().open("loc.txt");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    text = new String(buffer);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
this.city = text;
```

Here is where I compare the strings

```
Toast.makeText(this, city + " this is name stored as city in onMapReady in map activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
double lat, lon;
city.trim();
if (city.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Dublin")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, city + " getting into dublin in map activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    lat = 53.343908;
    lon = -6.267554;
}
```

It prints Dublin before the if statement but never reaches inside.
Thanks

Comment: You say "It prints dublin" but do you mean to say "It prints Dublin?"  Is the 'd' upper or lower case?

Comment: Sorry no I meant it prints Dublin, will change now

Comment: Have you tried equalsIgnoreCase and trimming the string?

Comment: if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Dublin")) did not work

Comment: trim() both of the strings

Comment: city.trim();
        if (city.equalsIgnoreCase("Dublin"))

didnt work

Comment: city.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Dublin")

Comment: just tried that, still no luck

Comment: either the characters don't match or it reads up trailing \r\n or spaces etc. see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712115/java-how-read-a-file-line-by-line-by-ignoring-n

Comment: I suggest two things: For debugging purposes, print city.length and also enclose city between brackets when printing: `System.out.println("["+city+"("+city.length()+")]");`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. By checking the length of the String, it said lenght was 7 when it should have been 6. I had my text file saved as UTF-8 rather than ANSI. when i changed it length was 6 and the program worked fine.